# AWS - Adjusting Database Links for Use with DB Instances in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to create a security group of a DB to allow ingress to and egress from another DB, but in the source I have to enter a valid CIDR (e.g. 0.0.0.0/0), and I don't know where I can get this CIDR from.
I tried to set the DB Endpoint `hotelsdbtest.cwob1oxhu1so.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, but is not a valid CIDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to provide a CIDR value in the source field, you can also provide a source security group ID. In your situation you need to use the security group IDs to grant access from one security group to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the CIDR from AWS console in database RDS  section. You can get that dB CIDR by following these points.

1. Go to RDS section
2. Click on instances
3. Click on your dB and expand its details
4. In security and network section there will be subnets
5. Click on subnets one by one if they are more than 1.
6. It will redirect you to VPC dashboard and note down the column value with the name of IPv4 CIDR and that would be your CIDR which you need to use.
7. It's mostly the 5th column in aws console.